# Grouped radiobuttons check changed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am currently working on a project where we render a dynamic page based on what we are holidng in a SQL table. We have conditional validation for controls where you can say

> if x is equal to y then enable controls abc

I have multiple radio buttons in a group, the last control is "Other (please specify)" which when true will enable a textbox to specify so I need to capture when this is set to both true or false. Currently I am doing something like this

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" onchange="onChange()" name="test" value="No" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onChange() {
        alert('Changed')
    }
</script>
```

If I check `NO` I get an alert. If I then check `YES` it changes the `NO` radio button checkstate but doesn't display an alert - any solutions?

Comment: Because `onChange` is defined for `NO` value only.

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS indeed it is, but surely the checked value has changed when I click `YES` because it removes the check from `NO` if you understand me?

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS: I think the point is that it is changing as a reaction to clicking the yes button. It isn't being clicked but it is getting changed.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is putting an onchange on the whole group and then checking which is selected when they change. Not very elegant but it appears that this is just how the change event works.

Comment: @Chris I should of elaborated on this in my question, because I am rendering the controls dynamically it will only ever put the event on one control because I am only conditionally validating one control value, I was hoping there would be an alternative to the change event somebody could suggest if not I will have to adapt to what you have said :(

Comment: Yeah. I don't know for a fact that there is no better way than my suggestion (which is why I didn't feel comfortable putting it in an answer). Here's hoping.

Comment: @Chris well i've endeded up doing what you suggested I knew this as my fall back option but I have a deadline to meet so I have just gone with this, it just makes the whole thing feel dirty and incorrect. I'd tick your comment but I can't :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is putting an onchange on the whole group and then checking which is selected when they change. Not very elegant but it appears that this is just how the change event works (ie it only responds to a user change, not to a system change of it).